# Export Wikipedia by category option?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I know I can download Wikipedia entirely. But I wonder if there is any way to download it by category? They have the [Special Export](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3aExport) page but writing a category (e.g. Culture) adds the children pages and another bunch of categories, so trying to get all the pages in Culture is gonna take "forever", because as you submit another sub categories of culture another show up. Do you guys know of any other way to export it by category? (in a simple way)

Comment: you might want to try this php script: https://github.com/produnis/myscripts/blob/master/PHP/mwc2pdf.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is any other simple way to do that.

I think your best bet is to download the dump file of all articles (`pages-articles`, currently 7.5 GB for the English Wikipedia) and filter them by category, possibly using the category membership dump (`categorylinks`, 1 GB).

Another option is do something similar to what you would do using Special:Export manually, but automate it using [the API](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php).

Comment: thank you for your great answer :) I'll try to do it that way

Comment: @Andrew how did you solve your problem? I need to do something similar. I want to obtain all the pages inside History Category recursively, something like https://petscan.wmflabs.org/ but using the mysql dumps

Answer (score 4):

Using the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API), you can get the wikitext of all pages in a category by using [`list=categorymembers`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aCategorymembers) as a [generator](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aGenerator) for a [`prop=revisions`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv) query, like this:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Culture&gcmnamespace=0&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

This example link gives the content of the first 10 articles in [Category:Culture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aCulture) on Wikipedia.  You can add the `gcmlimit=max` parameter to get more pages, but for large categories you'll need to handle [query continuations](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aGenerator#Continuing_queries) properly (or use a [MediaWiki API client](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code) that handles them for you).

(However, this query won't show pages in *subcategories* of Category:Culture.  If you want those too, you can get a list of the pages *and* subcategories in a category using a simple `categorymembers` query without `cmnamespace` and recurse through the results to collect a list of article titles to export.  If you do that, be careful not to get caught in any category loops, and preferably do a sanity check on the results before exporting the pages — it's very easy to get *way* more pages than you expected from a full subcategory traversal.)

Comment: I've downloaded Wikipedia pages, category and category links. I have them all in the database now. :)